# Процесс: вышивание или вышивка?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Когда говоришь о результате, то ясно, что это будет "вышивка". Но сам процесс? Можно ли сказать "В процессе вышивки нужно сделать то-то и то-то"? Или все-таки "В процессе вышивания"?

Answer (score 1):

Можно. Вполне. 
Только значения, думается, несколько разные.

Сидит человек и вышивает - он занимается вышиванием. В данный момент.
Человек представил несколько своих работ на конкурс - он занимается вышивкой. Вообще, как хобби.

Субъективно. Но тоже самое со многими отглагольными существительными. Поэтому и не катит пример с распечаткой.  Парного глагола "распечатывание" к ней нет, во всяком случае - в активном употреблении в данном значении. С отливкой, кстати, тоже не очень здорово все проходит. Существительное "отливание" или подобное - тоже нонсенс. Но тут я не самый большой спец, хотя в одной из прошлых жизней с имел дело и с отливками, хотя и косвенно.

Comment: В  приведённом  примере  значения  этих  слов  практически  одинаковы.  Вполне  взаимозаменяемы.

Comment: Какие? вышивка-вышивание? Ну *практически* - как раз не очень.
"вышивка"
Результатов: примерно 35 500 000 (0,25 сек.) 
вышивание
Результатов: примерно 3 300 000 (0,18 сек.)
Это если практически.